# Using libccv with UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, computer-vision

Let's say I have a UIImage (or NSData) object and my goal is to use it with libccv without having to write anything to disk beforehand. My problem is that I don't know how to get from such object to a ccv_dense_matrix_t.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming 0.2 release, I overloaded ccv_read function so that you can read a memory region into ccv. First you can get CGImageRef from UIImage (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html), from there, you can create a ccv_dense_matrix_t object (whether copied or not up to you) using ccv_read as simple as:

```
ccv_dense_matrix_t* x = 0;
ccv_read(data, &x, CCV_IO_ARGB_RAW | CCV_IO_GRAY, height, width, stepSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

The library only offers ccv_read() to do this conversion in the published API. If you read the code for this function you might find internal functions you can link to that accept a data pointer.

That said, why go to the trouble when you can just save the data in a file in the app's tmp directory with a few iOS API calls? If the file is small, you create it, use it, then delete it may never actually get written to flash - it would just reside in the system cache.

Comment: My goal is to try to replace OpenCV with libccv in order to detect an object in a scene in "real time" (using the camera). That's why every millisecond is precious and I don't want to write anything to disk. However, I might try what you said and hope the cache will work this way.